# JavaScript: window.open() opens incorrect path?

Tags: javascript

This function:

```
function mypopup()
{
    mywindow = window.open("http://www.mort3za.ir/somehtml.html", 
                           "mywindow", 
                           "menubar=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,  width=500,height=500");
    mywindow.moveTo(300, 50);
}
```

opens a popup with "mort3za.ir" address instead of "mort3za.ir/popup.html".

Internet Explorer 9 opens the correct path, so my problem is actually with [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) and Firefox.

Comment: Your problem must be with cache, it works here. Try hitting `CTRL+F5`

Comment: Unrelated: there are to be no spaces in the third argument.

Comment: I updated my answer - it seems that REFERER is making your server confused, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to the right page. The site is responding with a 302 to redirect the browser to the URL you're seeing.

*edit* — it's not clear *why* it's responding with a 302; just typing the URL into the address bar goes to the popup page.

*edit again* — oh I see - your host doesn't like it when the popup page is accessed with a "REFERER" value that's unrecognized (or something).  If I tell Firefox not to send REFERER, then your page does the right thing.

Comment: thanks! problem was from an auto generated .htaccess file. i removed auto generated lines of it.

Comment: this was auto generated lines of .htaccess:

`# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW HOTLINKID:kUSwYZ
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mort3za.ir/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mort3za.ir$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mort3za.ir/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mort3za.ir$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(txt|html|htm|php|swf)$ http://mort3za.ir [R,NC]
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE kUSwYZ:HOTLINKID`